# How to add strikethrough in the js tree according condition?

Tags: javascript, php, css, jstree

I have created a jsTree to show the folder pathname. My problem is how do I add a strikethrough according to the condition active or inactive in the JSTree ? Hope someone can guide me to solve this problem. Below is my code:

```html
<?php 
   $folderData = mysqli_query($mysql_con,"SELECT * FROM filing_code_management");
    $arr_sql5 = db_conn_select($folderData);
    foreach ($arr_sql5 as $rs_sql5) {
    $active = $rs_sql5['status'];
}
   $folders_arr = array();
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($folderData)){
      $parentid = $row['parentid'];
      if($parentid == '0') $parentid = "#";

      $selected = false;$opened = false;
      if($row['id'] == 2){
         $selected = true;$opened = true;
      }
      $folders_arr[] = array(
         "id" => $row['id'],
         "parent" => $parentid,
         "text" => $row['name'] . ' ' . "<span id='category'>". $row['category']."</span>",
         "category" => $row['category'],
         "state" => array("selected" => $selected,"opened"=>$opened) 
      );
   }

   ?> -->

 <!-- Initialize jsTree -->
   <div id="folder_jstree" title=""></div>
   <!-- Store folder list in JSON format -->
   <textarea style="" id='txt_folderjsondata'><?= json_encode($folders_arr) ?></textarea>


<script style="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var folder_jsondata = JSON.parse($('#txt_folderjsondata').val());

    $('#folder_jstree').jstree({
      'core': {
        'data': folder_jsondata,
        'multiple': false
      },
      'plugins': ['sort'],
      'sort': function(a, b) {
        return this.get_text(a).localeCompare(this.get_text(b), 'en', {
          numeric: true
        });
      }
    });

    var getColor = function(i) {
      if (i >= 100 && i <= 199) {
        return "blue";
      } else if (i >= 200 && i <= 299) {
        return "red";
      } else if (i >= 300 && i <= 399) {
        return "yellow";
      } else if (i >= 400 && i <= 499) {
        return "purple";
      } else if (i >= 500 && i <= 599) {
        return "green";
      } else {
        return "#000";
      }
    };

    var colorNodes = function(nodelist) {
      var tree = $('#folder_jstree').jstree(true);
      nodelist.forEach(function(n) {
        tree.get_node(n.id).a_attr.style = "color:" + getColor(parseInt(n.text.substr(0, 3), 10));
        tree.redraw_node(n.id); //Redraw tree
        colorNodes(n.children); //Update leaf nodes
      });
    };

    $('#folder_jstree').bind('load_node.jstree', function(e, data) {
      var tree = $('#folder_jstree').jstree(true);
      colorNodes(tree.get_json());
    });

    $('#folder_jstree').bind('hover_node.jstree', function(e, data) {
      $("#" + data.node.id).attr("title", data.node.original.category);
    });

  });


  /*   $(function() {
        $(document).tooltip();
      });  */

</script>
```

Inside **json_encode($folders_arr)** the content is:

```html
[{"id":"1","parent":"#","text":"100 PENTADBIRAN <span id='category'>JTM<\/span>","category":"JTM","state":{"selected":false,"opened":false}},{"id":"2","parent":"#","text":"200 PENGURUSAN TANAH & BANGUNAN <span id='category'>JTM<\/span>","category":"JTM","state":{"selected":true,"opened":true}},{"id":"3","parent":"#","text":"300 PENGURUSAN ASET <span id='category'>JTM<\/span>","category":"JTM","state":{"selected":false,"opened":false}},{"id":"4","parent":"#","text":"400 PENGURUSAN KEWANGAN <span id='category'>JKP<\/span>","category":"JKP","state":{"selected":false,"opened":false}},{"id":"5","parent":"#","text":"500 PENGURUSAN SUMBER MANUSIA <span id='category'>JKP<\/span>","category":"JKP","state":{"selected":false,"opened":false}},{"id":"6","parent":"1","text":"100-1 PERUNDANGAN <span id='category'>JTM<\/span>","category":"JTM","state":{"selected":false,"opened":false}},{"id":"7","parent":"1","text":"100-2 PERHUBUNGAN AWAM <span id='category'>JKP<\/span>","category":"JKP","state":{"selected":false,"opened":false}},{"id":"8","parent":"6","text":"100-1-1 PENGGUBALAN-PENYEDIAAN-PINDAAN UNDANG-UNDANG-PERATURAN <span id='category'>JTM<\/span>","category":"JTM","state":{"selected":false,"opened":false}},{"id":"9","parent":"6","text":"100-1-2 KHIDMAT NASIHAT <span id='category'>JTM<\/span>","category":"JTM","state":{"selected":false,"opened":false}},{"id":"10","parent":"8","text":"100-1-1-1 UNDANG-UNDANG KECIL KERJA DI JALAN 1996 <span id='category'>JTM<\/span>","category":"JTM","state":{"selected":false,"opened":false}},{"id":"11","parent":"8","text":"100-1-1-2 UNDANG-UNDANG KECIL PERUNTUKAN MENGENAI LESEN BERSESAMA (MAJLIS PERBANDARAN) <span id='category'>JTM<\/span>","category":"JTM","state":{"selected":false,"opened":false}},{"id":"12","parent":"8","text":"100-1-1-3 UNDANG-UNDANG KECIL MENGKOMPAUN KESALAHAN-KESALAHAN (MAJLIS PERBANDARAN KLANG), JALAN PARIT DAN <span id='category'>JTM (BERHUBUNG KOD 100-1\/1\/2)<\/span>","category":"JTM (BERHUBUNG KOD 100-1\/1\/2)","state":{"selected":false,"opened":false}},{"id":"13","parent":"9","text":"100-1-2-1 JABATAN PENGUATKUASAAN <span id='category'>JTM<\/span>","category":"JTM","state":{"selected":false,"opened":false}},{"id":"14","parent":"9","text":"100-1-2-2 JABATAN BANGUNAN <span id='category'>JTM<\/span>","category":"JTM","state":{"selected":false,"opened":false}},{"id":"15","parent":"7","text":"100-2-1 PUBLISITI, PROMOSI DAN PROTOKOL <span id='category'>JKP<\/span>","category":"JKP","state":{"selected":false,"opened":false}},{"id":"16","parent":"15","text":"100-2-1-1 PUBLISITI DAN KENYATAAN MEDIA <span id='category'>JKP<\/span>","category":"JKP","state":{"selected":false,"opened":false}},{"id":"84","parent":"#","text":"201 HAHA <span id='category'>JTM<\/span>","category":"JTM","state":{"selected":false,"opened":false}}]
```

I want the condition such that if **$active = 0** then it will show the strikethrough in the jsTree. Else if **$active = 1** then it will back to normal.

Actually I want the actual output like the below sample picture. For the output below I just used Paint software to edit, easier to let you know what I want as the output:

[image: Output 1]

My working JSFiddle code is here: https://jsfiddle.net/ason5861_cs/9x0dsotz/2/

Hope someone can guide me on how to add strikethrough according to the condition active or inactive into my code?

**Note：**$row['name'] and $row['category']needed to put strikethrough together if inactive.

Comment: You might need to pass the `active` flag in the `$folders_arr` for all nodes so that jsTree can be used to create a strikethrough

Comment: Thanks @Stephen S. Can you show me how to pass the active flag in the JS fiddle?

Comment: you&#39;ll have to add it in the php code. Can&#39;t help much with php part, it&#39;s been quite a while that I worked on it  and I am not really sure I understand the logic here..

Comment: Ok. Nevermind. Thanks

Comment: tree.get_node(n.id).a_attr.style = "color:" + getColor(parseInt(n.text.substr(0, 3), 10)); can replace this function to do it? @StephenS

Comment: Yes, you could add logic there to add a strikethrough, but you need the active flag in the json to determine when to do a strikethrough.

Comment: Ok. I go to try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With PHP you could have your conditional to set the value of a NULL variable to text-decoration that changes to line-through. This would be done with CSS. Simply have a conditional that checks if the value of $active is set to 0, if it is, then set the value of the null variable to display line-through. If the value of active is anything other than 0, then $strikeThrough will stay NULL and output nothing, therefor no change to text style that is wrapped in span tag.

```
$strikeThrough = null;
if($active = 0){
$strikeThrough = 'text-decoration: line-through;'
    $output = "<span style='".$strikeThrough."'>" . $rs_wtpname . "</span>";
}
// no change needed for default Active
```

IN JS, you could use the `#folder_jstree` `nodelist` to run through your list and update there. Likely within your colorNodes function you could have a conditional there to check the value of status, then append css to your value if set to 0 (inactive).

If you are unable to get the status from PHP into JS, you could dump the value in the php code using the aforementioned method into an arbitrary data attribute or even alt attribute added to the `#folder_jstree` element span tag. Then retrieve that using JS and perform your conditional in JS.

***EDIT:*** *(April 25th, 2020)*

Okay I think I see what you are doing with the JSON and your $folders_array now and how it is saving the data to be parsed in the JSON file.

Try the following code in your php and see if it works.

```php
$folderData = mysqli_query($mysql_con,"SELECT * FROM filing_code_management");
    $arr_sql5 = db_conn_select($folderData);
    foreach ($arr_sql5 as $rs_sql5) {
    $active = $rs_sql5['status']; //--> Here you are setting active state
}
$folders_arr = array();
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($folderData)){
      $parentid = $row['parentid'];
      if($parentid == '0') $parentid = "#";

      $selected = false;$opened = false;
      if($row['id'] == 2){
         $selected = true;$opened = true;
      }

      //--> this would be the default state of active = 1 set in $output
      $output = $row['name'] . ' ' . "<span id='category'>". $row['category']."</span>";
      //--> Now we see if active is set to 0
      if($active === 0){
          //--> if active is set to 0 change the value of $output to reflect 'text-decoration'
          $output = "<span style='text-decoration: line-through;'>" . $row['name'] . ' ' . "<span id='category'>". $row['category']."</span></span>";
      }
      $folders_arr[] = array(
         "id" => $row['id'],
         "parent" => $parentid,
         "text" => $output, //--> save the proper $output in our array
         "category" => $row['category'],
         "state" => array("selected" => $selected,"opened"=>$opened) 
      );
   }
```

Comment: Thanks @dale landry answer my question again. Can you put your code to combine with my code or put in my Jsfiddle? Because my combination got something wrong to show in the page.

Comment: How are you trying to set it? In php or JS?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ason5861_cs/r0xwcv4d/4/ Is any I am getting wrong here?

Comment: You need to place the conditional below the query, when you run your query, you follow up with a foreach loop that defines the variable $active, so you must check the status of active after you define it. Try adding the if statement that defines $output in the $arr_sql5 loop, after you define $active. Then check the status and set your output. From there I think you are passing the data through to $folder_arr? You need to place $output into a tags style attribute that is wrapped around the data that ends up displaying the strkethrough text.

Comment: How to write strike through variable like var getColor = function(i) in JS

Comment: Sorry Dale Landry, I don't know how to use your concept to put my code.If possible your concept code combine with my code?

Comment: `tree.get_node(n.id).a_attr.style = "color:" + getColor(parseInt(n.text.substr(0, 3), 10));` This is the line that colors your elements correct? Your loop is the colorNodes variable correct? How are you determining active status in JS? JavaScript is not my strong point, but I may be able to help.

Comment: How are you adding the active status in JS?

Comment: This is problem for me to add the active status in JS

Comment: @Ong I think I have code that will work for you to send to JSON file already set to active or not within PHP. See my edit for today.